# Populating loading cache while loading from DB

Tags: java, caching, guava

Am using loading cache to cache the result of the query. As far as I know, If the key is not found in cache, it will load from DB. While loading will it populate the cache simultaneously?

```
CacheLoader <String, Obj> Loader = new CacheLoader<String, Obj>() {
        @Override
        public Obj load(String key) throws Exception {                    
                Obj obj = ObjDao.getDs().createQuery(Obj.class).filter("id ==", key).get();                    
                return obj;                                   
        }
};
```

Comment: Yes, the [CacheLoader](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) as used in a [LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) retrieves values that are _stored in the cache until either evicted or manually invalidated_. It's all in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html):

> Values are automatically loaded by the cache, and are stored in the cache until either evicted or manually invalidated.

[LoadingCache.get(K)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get(K)):

> Returns the value associated with `key` in this cache, first loading that value if necessary. No observable state associated with this cache is modified until loading completes.
>
> If another call to [`get(K)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get(K)) or [`getUnchecked(K)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#getUnchecked(K)) is currently loading the value for `key`, simply waits for that thread to finish and returns its loaded value. Note that multiple threads can concurrently load values for distinct keys.
>
> Caches loaded by a [`CacheLoader`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) will call [`CacheLoader.load(K)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html#load(K)) to load new values into the cache. Newly loaded values are added to the cache using `Cache.asMap().putIfAbsent` after loading has completed; if another value was associated with key while the new value was loading then a removal notification will be sent for the new value.